# Java - чтение csv файлов с помощью DAO

Tags: java, csv, dao

Стоит задача создавать и записывать обьекты с файла csv.  В данный момент стоит задача сделать связь контролера с базой админов, так как в java только начинающий - интересует правильно ли составлен код? А также админ, который залогинится должен будет иметь доступ к остальным админам, правильно ли будет создать еще один метод который добавляет все обьекты админов в ArrayList. ? Хочу услышать комментарии по коду.

Controller:

```
    AOAdmin admin = new DAOAdmin();

    Admin admin1 = admin.load("cc12954", "123345");
```

DAO:

```
public class DAOAdmin implements AdminDao{

private static final String basePath = "/Users/valik/Desktop/queststore-system-team_power/src/Admins.csv";

public DAOAdmin() {

}

public Admin load(String id, String password) {

    try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(basePath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(br);

        while(scnr.hasNextLine()){

            String line = scnr.nextLine();
            String nLine [] = line.split(",");
            if(nLine[4].equals(id) && nLine[2].equals(password)) {
                Admin a = createAdminFromRow(nLine);
                return a;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }return new Admin();
}



public void saveAdmin(){
    System.out.println("not implemented");
}

public Admin createAdminFromRow(String[] nLine){

    Admin a = new Admin();
    String AdmLogin = nLine[4];
    String AdmName = nLine[0];

    a.setName(AdmName);
    a.setLogin(AdmLogin);

    return a;


   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java конвенция](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) 
раздел Constants

```
private static final String basePath = "/Users/valik/Desktop/queststore-system-team_power/src/Admins.csv";
```

Заменяем на

```
private static final String BASE_PATH = "/Users/valik/Desktop/queststore-system-team_power/src/Admins.csv";
```

раздел Variables

```
String AdmLogin = nLine[4];
String AdmName = nLine[0];
```

Заменяем на

```
String login = nLine[4];
String name = nLine[0];
```

Хардкодить полный путь не стоит, [используем ресурсы](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/)

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "Admins.csv";
File csvFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILE_NAME).getFile());
```

[Закрываем IO ресурсы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) и [отдельно обрабатываем ошибки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile)))) {
...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("File not found");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to read file " + e.getMessage());
```

}

В итоге получилось

```
public class DAOAdmin {

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "Admins.csv";

    public Admin load(String id, String password) {
        File csvFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILE_NAME).getFile());

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile)))) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String nLine[] = line.split(",");
                if (nLine[4].equals(id) && nLine[2].equals(password)) {
                    return createAdminFromRow(nLine);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to read file " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return new Admin();
    }

    public void saveAdmin() {
        System.out.println("not implemented");
    }

    public Admin createAdminFromRow(String[] nLine) {
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        String login = nLine[4];
        String name = nLine[0];

        admin.setName(login);
        admin.setLogin(name);

        return admin;
    }
}
```

Или используя Java 8

```
public class DAOAdmin implements AdminDao {
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "Admins.csv";

    public Admin load(String id, String password) {
        Path filePath = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(FILE_NAME).getFile());

        try {
            return Files.lines(filePath)
                    .map(line -> line.split(","))
                    .filter(parts -> parts[4].equals(id) && parts[2].equals(password))
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(this::parseAdmin)
                    .orElseGet(Admin::new);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to read csv " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return new Admin();
    }

    private Admin parseAdmin(String parts[]) {
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        admin.setName(parts[4]);
        admin.setLogin(parts[0]);
        return admin;
    }
}
```